# How to display rich:notify notification after clicking a a4j:commandButton?

Tags: jsf

After clicking a a4j:commandButton, i want to display a rich:notify that contain a message from my Model ?

How to trigger this notification just after clicking my commandButton ?

Here is the code that i use :

** *DataTable* *********

```
<rich:dataTable id="currencyDataTable"  value="#{s2MCurrencyModel.getAllS2MCurrency()}"
                var="currency" border="1">

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Task ID</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{currency.taskId}" />
                </rich:column>
........
                <rich:column>
                    <h:form>

                        <a4j:commandButton value="Delete"
                            render="currencyDeleteInfo"
                            oncomplete="#{rich:component('currencyDelete')}.show()"
                            disabled="#{!currency.status.equals('I')}">
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener
                                target="#{s2MCurrencyModel.selectedCurrency}"
                                value="#{currency}" />
                        </a4j:commandButton>
                    </h:form>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>

<!-- =============   DELETE BOX  =============== -->
    <rich:popupPanel id="currencyDelete">
        <f:facet name="header">currency delete confirmation</f:facet>
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:outputLink value="#"
                onclick="#{rich:component('currencyDelete')}.hide(); return false;">
                X
             </h:outputLink>
        </f:facet>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid id="currencyDeleteInfo">
                Do you want really to delete currency identified by: 
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{s2MCurrencyModel.selectedCurrency.currencyCode}" />

                <h:panelGroup>
                <a4j:commandButton value="Delete"
                    oncomplete="#{rich:component('currencyDelete')}.hide();return false"
                    action="#{s2mCurrencyCtrl.deleteCurrency()}"
                    render="currencyDataTable"
                    />
                    **<rich:notify detail="#{s2MCurrencyModel.message}" stayTime="5000" summary="Notification" showShadow="true" />**
                <h:button value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('currencyDelete')}.hide(); return false;"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </rich:popupPanel>

                    render="currencyDataTable"
                    />
                    <rich:notify detail="#{myModel.message}" stayTime="5000" />
```

i set myModel.message in deleteCurrency() method.

Regards,

Comment: Does the rich:notify element is inside the currencyDataTable container? Can you please expose the whole code?

Comment: No, rich:notify is outside DataTable, above updated code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `FacesMessage` to the `FacesContext` in the action of your command button like so:

```
public void deleteCurrency(){
//your other operations
FacesContext ctx = this.getCurrentInstance();
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Detail","Summary"); //FacesMessage has other info levels
ctx.addMessage(null,msg);
}
```

Comment: Not works, notification is showed after each action (page load, click). but how to specify FacesMessage to rich:notify component in xhtml page ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is the notification showing up when you click on the desired button @Ouadi?

Comment: it's showing on page load in first, and after clicking any button !

Comment: @Ouadi then that is you doing something wrong. The code snippet that I've shown here should be put in a code block that should execute only when needed. `detail="#{myModel.message}"` is unnecessary, this is why it's showing up without cause. Use only the code snippet to add a message to the FacesContext.

Comment: Thanks @kolossus for your clarification

I've solve my probelem with this code :

    <a4j:commandButton value="Delete"
      oncomplete="#{rich:component('currencyDelete')}.hide();return false"
      action="#{s2mCurrencyCtrl.deleteCurrency()}"
      render="currencyDataTable"
      >
      <rich:notifyMessages stayTime="5000" showShadow="true" />
     </a4j:commandButton>

Thanks,

Comment: @Ouadi, because you're using the same string for the `detail` and `summary` attributes of the `FacesMessage`. Use different texts or disable one of them on the `<rich:notify/>` component

Comment: I was disable them, but the same issue, here is my code : <rich:notifyMessage showDetail="false" showSummary="true" showCloseButton="true"  stayTime="5000" showShadow="true" />

Comment: @Ouadi, look at your code, you have two `<rich:notify/>`s on your page

Comment: I've changed it to <rich:notifyMessage >